# Knowledge works in "try it", but agent does not recognize intent and retrieve $Knowledge.Answer

Tags: dialogflow-es

I know this is in Beta, but I've set up a Knowledge base for my agent and the intent doesn't seem to get recognized.

When setting up the Knowledge base, the "try it" test works and retrieves successfully, but when trying the same request from the simple chat bot, the intent is not recognized. What else is necessary to hook the Knowledge feature to the agent?

Comment: This is not related to programming, is it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the medium of that simple chat bot you are using?Is it android/web?

**Assuming are using dialogflow v2 node.js library**,We have to pass the full path of the knowledgeBase in the queryParams inside the detectIntent function request object.Then only dialogflow will look into knowledgeBase for matching the user input to the Knowledge base Intents.

Sample of request object-

```
// const projectId = 'ID of GCP project associated with your Dialogflow agent';
// const sessionId = `user specific ID of session, e.g. 12345`;
   const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
    let request = {
        session: sessionPath,  
        queryInput: {
          text: {
            text: 'hi,how are you?',
            languageCode: 'en-US',
          },
        },
        queryParams: {
          knowledgeBaseNames:['projects/stockmarket-XXXX/knowledgeBases/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXx']         //Paste your knowledge base path,Check this out from the diagnostic info
        }
      };
```

checkout https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.v2beta1.js#L438

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: this is exactly how I have my code configured and the service is not retrieving KnowledgeBase responses at all.